# Text has been reflected in 3D plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot, tikz-shape

It seems that the text `xz` on the x-z plane of the 3D figure below has been reflected.

How to make it normal, just like `yz` on the y-z plane?

[image: 3d-plane-text]

---

[<del>Editable</del> Read-only code on ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/581d9c9a7299190d58abe41a)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]

\coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (x) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (y) at (0,1,0);
\coordinate (z) at (0,0,1);

\draw[thick, >=Stealth, ->] (O) -- (x) node[anchor = north]{x}; % x
\draw[thick, >=Stealth, ->] (O) -- (y) node[anchor = north]{y}; % y
\draw[thick, >=Stealth, ->] (O) -- (z) node[anchor = south]{z}; % z

\coordinate (xz) at (1,0,1);
\coordinate (yz) at (0,1,1);

% text on the yz plane
\draw[canvas is yz plane at x = 0, transform shape, draw = red, fill = red!50, opacity = 0.5] (yz) rectangle (O);
\node[canvas is yz plane at x = 0] at (0,0.5,0.5) {yz};

% text on the xz plane (Notice: it seems that the text has been reflected)
\draw[canvas is xz plane at y = 0, transform shape, draw = blue, fill = blue!50, opacity = 0.5] (xz) rectangle (O);
\node[canvas is xz plane at y = 0, align = center] at (0.5,0,0.5){xz};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea how this plot can be extended to include an xy plane? I keep getting an unfortunately placed rectangle. Thanks!

Comment: @Tyler It seems that the way of `\coordinate (xy) at (1,1,0); \draw[canvas is xy plane at z = 0, draw = red, fill = red!50, opacity = 0.5] (xy) rectangle (O);` does *not* work. A workaround here: `\coordinate (xy) at (1,1,0); \filldraw[fill = green!50, opacity = 0.5] (xy) -- (x) -- (O) -- (y) -- cycle; \node[canvas is xy plane at z = 0] at (0.5,0.5,0) {xy};`. See [the code](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/581d9c9a7299190d58abe41a).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea why it's reflected, but you can reflect it back

```
\node[canvas is xz plane at y = 0, align = center] at (0.5,0,0.5){\reflectbox{xz}};
```

produces

[image]

Comment: It is reflected because the transformation matrix to that plane has a negative determinant. If you were to rotate it such that `x` points right, the usual orientation would be restored.